# Multiple Callback issue in Nservicebus 5

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, nservicebus

```
public static  SynchronousCommandReply SendMessageSynchronous<TMessage>(this IBus bus, TMessage message, int requestTimeoutMilliseconds)
        where TMessage : class
    {
        var response = new SynchronousCommandReply();
        ManualResetEvent waitForReply = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        var asyncResult = bus.Send(message).Register(ar =>{
            var completionResult = (CompletionResult)ar.AsyncState;
            Contract.Assume(completionResult != null);
            response = (SynchronousCommandReply)completionResult.Messages[0];
            Contract.Assume(response != null);
            waitForReply.Set();
        }, null);

        if (!waitForReply.WaitOne(requestTimeoutMilliseconds))
        {
            throw new ResponseTimeoutException("Timeout waiting for response.");
        }

        return response;}
```

Saga:

```
 this.Bus.Reply(synchronousCommandReply);
```

It's throwing time out error on second call back even though saga completed successfully.

Please refer this link:
https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2748

I too had the same issue. So I issued **ManualResetEvent** in my code. Even then the error persist.

I got stuck for past one week. Please give suggestion to proceed further

Comment: I would avoid using the callback feature. If you need to do request response in a bounded context, use sagas to choreograph your message processing.

Comment: Can you provide a sample to reproduce this (in github/dropbox)?

Comment: @sean, "The sample makes use of multiple serial callbacks and also uses ReplyToOriginator multiple times. Now ReplyToOriginator has been designed to always reply to the callback of the message from which the saga originated, hence both replies would attempt to get back to the first callback and in case of a reply to the second command it cannot find that callback anymore as it had already been invoked." this is my issue.

Comment: @cj can you provide a repro project please? Maybe open a support case by sending the details to support at particular.net?